# Symfony ProcessTimedOutException when running gulp --production

Tags: symfony, gulp, composer-php, php-deployer

When i run my deploy file on my server. I get time out error exception. I increase my composer process-timeout ("process-timeout":600). Also, i added timeout in deploy.php

Here deploy.php:

```
task('gulp', function(){
    cd('release');
    run('gulp --production', ['timeout' => null]);
})->desc('Running Gulp');
```

Exception:

[TimedoutException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHATW.jpg)

Comment: Also i added set('default_timeout', 600); in deploy.php but did not work

Comment: After one and half day, i solved the problem by changing run('gulp --production', ['timeout' => null]); to runLocally('cd ... && gulp --production', 900); My deployer version is 3. If you updated to v5 then use run('gulp --production', ['timeout' => null]);